# String formatting as per current locale

Tags: c#

In my C# application I am using string as

```
string sTemp = "10.12;12.13;15.345";
```

Now I would like to know is there any way I could format this string and its contents(specially when they are numbers) as per current locale. Ultimately I want my sTemp should be -  "10,12;12,13;15,345" in french locale.

Is it possible?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your current code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Are you building this string content or assigning it the text ?

Comment: @Oded - Currently I have not tried much on this front , I just needed way to achieve this so that I can decide on my future approach.From next time I will surely keep in mine to add What I have tried , a good lesson.Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string sTemp = "10.12;12.13;15.345";
string[] splitted = sTemp.Split(';');
IEnumerable<float> floats = splitted.Select(s => float.Parse(s, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

string localized = floats.Select(f => f.ToString()).Aggregate((current, next) => current + ";" + next);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.Split(';')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to split the string-doubles, [`double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447.aspx) with  [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) to parse the input and [`double.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx) with [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) (or "fr-FR") to parse the output:

```
string sTemp = "10.12;12.13;15.345";

var doubles = sTemp.Split(';')
    .Select(s => double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

var locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
// or var locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

var localeDoubleStrings = doubles.Select(d => d.ToString(locale));
foreach(string frDoubleStr in localeDoubleStrings)
    Console.WriteLine(frDoubleStr);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ihOTBL)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the string with the contents as declared in that case you need to have it formatted

Example

```
// this would be as per french culture
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new CultureInfo("Fr-fr"), "{0};{1};{2};", 10.2, 15.6, 25.3));
// this would be invariant
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0};{1};{2};", 10.2, 15.6, 25.3));
```

so you would need to just say `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and that should work for you.

*But if you are using it with the contents then you have to update the question with how you are building the string content*